# Query to get number of related records in 2 child tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a category table (brands) and 2 other tables (`Pens` and `Pencils`) that have parent-child relation with this table through a field `CatID`.  Now I want to get a list of `Brands`and number of records in child tables.

I use this query:

```
Select 
  B.* ,COUNT(P.ID) as PensCount, COUNT(Pc.ID) as PencilsCount 
from 
  Brands B 
left outer join 
  Pens P on B.ID=P.CatID 
left outer join 
  Pencils Pc on B.ID= Pc.CatID 
group by 
  B.ID,B.Title;
```

Is this correct?  Is there any way to make this query better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try this query?  Did it work?  Unless ID and Title are the only columns in the Brands table this query would result in an error.

I would use subqueries for this:

```
SELECT
   Brands.*,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pens WHERE CatID = Brands.ID) AS PensCount,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pencils WHERE CatID = Brands.ID) AS PencilsCount
FROM 
   Brands
```